# Writing to the wrong class instance in java

Tags: java

NOTE: This code is a work in progress solution to an assignment in Discrete Optimization by Pascal Van Hentenryck on Coursera. Those of you who do not want to see possible solutions or hints might not want to read any further.

I am fairly new to Java so this might be a totally wrong code. But I have spent a while on this code with no progress. I am stepping through the code in eclipse.

When I step through the code below I am trying to update the instance of `branch[0]` but
when I update `branch[0].path` then `thisNode.path` gets updated too 
 and when I update `branch[1].path` then `branch[0].path` and `thisNode.path` gets updated too (at-least as the watch window shows).

What am I doing wrong here ?

```
void iterateOneStep(BnBNode thisNode, int next_path){
    BnBNode [] branch;

    branch = new BnBNode [2];

    //item not picked
    branch[0] = new BnBNode(items.size());
    branch[0].availableCapacity = thisNode.availableCapacity;
    branch[0].path = thisNode.path;
    branch[0].path[next_path] = 0;
    branch[0].val = thisNode.val;
    //item picked
    branch[1] = new BnBNode(items.size());
    branch[1].availableCapacity = thisNode.availableCapacity - items.get(next_path).weight;
    branch[1].path = thisNode.path;
    branch[1].path[next_path] = 1;
    branch[1].val = thisNode.val+items.get(next_path).value;
    ..............
```

The class BnBNode is

```
public class BnBNode {
    int[] path;
    int val;
    int availableCapacity;
    int potentialVal;
    int optimum;

    BnBNode(int numItems) {
        path = new int[numItems];
        numItems--;
        while (numItems >= 0) {
            path[numItems] = -1;
            numItems--;
        }
        val = 0;
        optimum = 0;
    }
}
```

The full code is at https://github.com/vinaysamuel/knapsack/tree/master/src

Thanks for your time,
Vinay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at these bits of code:

```
branch[0].path = thisNode.path;
...
branch[1].path = thisNode.path;
```

The type of `path` is an `int[]`, which means you're copying *references*. You've only actually got a single array object, and after the code above, all of `branch[0].path`, `thisNode.path` and `branch[1].path` refer to that single array.

You may wish to *clone* the array to create independent copies:

```
branch[0].path = thisNode.path.clone();
...
branch[1].path = thisNode.path.clone();
```

Comment: Doesn't `clone()` actually have the same static type as the cloned array for array types?

Comment: @user2357112: So it does - thanks, I'd forgotten that. (JLS section 10.7 for anyone interested.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account what type of element is `path`. If it's not a primitive, then when you do `branch[0].path = thisNode.path`, you're making `branch[0].path` point to `thisNode.path`. From that on, they're actually two references to the same object, and any change you do using any of the references will affect what you see through the other.